# How to use terminal commands to sign android app

Tags: android

I have built a system that allows my marketing department to manage our in house applications. The ubuntu server uses the SDK and terminal commands executed from PHP to create/build or update the application, so far this has worked very well for our off the play store (adult) applications. We are however looking at launching some of our new apps that meet the stores requirements on the store.

When you upload the application to the store it is required to be signed by a private key, could anyone point me in the right direction with regards to using the sdk and terminal commands to sign an application.

While the following page has plenty of information: 
http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

I was wondering if anyone else has done this before, and can help me with a code example instead of me banging my head against the wall for 8 hours.

thank you :D

Comment: Although I would `highly` recommend going through the resource:[Signing Your Applications](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html), this is what you are asking for: [ Tutorial on Signing your apk for publishing!](http://www.talkandroid.com/android-forums/android-market-reviews/1317-tutorial-signing-your-apk-publishing.html). And it will not take 8 hours. It will take as long as it should.

Comment: @Vikram The link to talkandroid.com is broken

Answer (score 15):

On the same page that you referenced in the question there is an example command for signing an apk.

> **Sign your application with your private key**
>
> When you have an application package that is ready to be signed, you can do sign it using the Jarsigner tool. Make sure that you have Jarsigner available on your machine, as described in Basic Setup. Also, make sure that the keystore containing your private key is available.
>
> To sign your application, you run Jarsigner, referencing both the application's APK and the keystore containing the private key with which to sign the APK. The table below shows the options you could use.

Generate a key store

```
$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Sign an apk.

```
$ jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore my_application.apk alias_name
```

---

In order to use the same keystore Android Studio uses to sign debug APKs, use

```
$ jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore my_application.apk androiddebugkey
```

and enter `android` passphrase.

---

Documentation: [Sign an apk](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#signapp)

Comment: On a side note, it might be a good idea to do a zipalign after signing.

Answer (score 0):

Successfully signed an apk by 3 lines of commands:

```
# 1. generate key by keytool
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias my-alias

# 2. zip align
/Users/jeff-tian/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/32.1.0-rc1/zipalign -v -p 4 jeff-tian-unsigned-unaligned.apk jeff-tian-unsigned-aligned.apk

# 3. sign
/Users/jeff-tian/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/32.1.0-rc1/apksigner sign --ks my-release-key.jks --out jeff-tian-release.apk jeff-tian-unsigned-aligned.apk
```

The keytool can be accessed by typing it directly, it should be installed with java.

The zipalign and apksigner is installed with android sdk, which is not directly accessible in my case. I found them by

```
find /Users/jeff-tian/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools -name "apksigner"
```

and

```
find /Users/jeff-tian/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools -name "zipalign"
```

The android sdk path can be found from android studio:

[image]

After signed I installed successfully in to my Huawei P20 and the smart TV, too. Good luck to you!

[image]

[image]